# What does y==x mean in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I came across some MATLAB code online and it was running just fine, but I couldn't understand the meaning of `(y == x)` where `y` is a column matrix and `x` is an integer.

```
someFunction(y == x);
```

Is it some kind of comparing or setting some value of `y`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instruction

```
y == x
```

checks which values in the array `y` (if any) are equals to the scalar `x` and returns a `logical` array of the size of `y` in which `1` is set in the location where the value of the element of `y` is equal to the value of `x` and `0` in the other case.

It ha to be assumed tha also the array `y` is of `integer` type, otherwise the comparison does not have sense.

Therefore, the function `someFunction` seems accepting as input a `logical` array.

As an example, with

```
y = [10     2    10     7     1     3     6    10    10     2]
```

and

```
x=10
```

the code

```
(y == x)
```

returns the logical array:

```
1     0     1     0     0     0     0     1     1     0
```

This will be the input `someFunction` function.

Hope this helps,

QWapla'